# Como converter um carácter em hexadecimal em Assembly

Tags: assembly, .net-assembly, webassembly

O meu código deve receber um carácter e imprimir o código em ASCII, porém não funciona e não consigo achar onde está o erro.
Edit: está dando o erro (41) Unexpected end of file encountered

```
model     small   
          stack     100h

$AsciiToHex  macro   asciiChar, hexStr2
          local  tableHex

          .data
tableHex  db   '0123456789ABCDEF'      

          .code                              
          Main      proc
          mov  ax, @data
          mov  ds, ax
          mov ah,01h
          int 21h
          mov  asciiChar, al
          $AsciiToHex  asciiChar, hexStr2
          mov  ax, word ptr [hexStr2] 
          mov   bx, offset  tableHex  
          mov   al, [asciiChar]        
          mov   ah, al                 
          and   al, 00001111b          
          xlat                          
          mov   [hexStr2 + 1], al     
          shr   ax, 8               
          xlat                         
          mov   hexStr2, al                    
          endp Main
          end  main
```

Answer (score 1):

De onde veio esse "12" ???

```
shr ax, 12
```

O certo é 8

```
shr ax, 8
```

porque 8 é o tamanho em bits dos registradores AH e AL, e lembrando, o registrador AX é composto pelos 2 sub-registradores AH e AL.

google: hello world masm
   [primeiro link](https://www.mentebinaria.com.br/forums/topic/146-hello-world-em-masm-no-windows/): aparentemente você precisa ter um label "main:" para casar com a diretiva "end main", provavelmente assim:

```
      .code                              
      Main   proc
main: mov    ax, @data
```

Comment: ainda está dando erro. Erro: Code cannot be assembled. One or more support file for this assembly code is missing.

Comment: pelo teor da mensagem, pode ser que esteja faltando o arquivo "equal-01.inc"

Comment: agora esá dizendo: **(41) Unexpected end of file encountered**